# stop unwanted traffic on the website

Tags: php, blocking, spam

I have unwanted traffic on my website.
for example.

1. Someone make a html or js file and open a webpage of my website.
2. Spam bots, which browse my website.

This type of traffic dont give me any benefit rather it is using bandwidth.

I want to know how to detect this type of traffic on my website and stop them.

If i come to know the ip address or referer url then i block that ip or referer url from htaccess. 
but in that case i have add ip or referer url each time. i want it automatic.
something like it detect or identify the spam hits and block them.

Comment: Welcome to the World Wide Web :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) to your web site root to prevent most automatic crawlers from accessing you site.

You could also come up with a rule that redirects access to error page if [Referrer](http://webdesign.about.com/od/loganalysis/a/aa100305.htm) is set (client comes through a link, search engine or such). This only allows direct access to the web site.

The real answer: **do not bother**

- Trying to limit unwanted access will most likely just hurt legitimate visitors.
- Setting up the limitations will cost more in time than the saved bandwidth is worth
- If you bandwidth is really so expensive, change service provider